# Parsing String json to List<Model>

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I just can not solve this problem. I get the data from the server, save them in shared preferences `key = data` `value = "[.. json]`.
The structure and type of data can be seen in the screenshot.

[image: sample image]

How to correctly json in the `List <User ..>`. I use this code, in which it uses jackson2 library, but it does not work. I'm getting an error

> JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.example.dmitriysamoilov.filipapp.model.UserContactListModel out of START_ARRAY token

```
public List<UserContactListModel> getUserLocalContactsData() {
    List<UserContactListModel> listModels = new ArrayList<>();
    String json = "";

    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(ReservedName.USER_LOCAL_CONTACTS_DATA,
            context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sharedPreferences.contains("json")) {
        json = sharedPreferences.getString("json", "");
    }else return listModels;

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        // Convert JSON string from file to Object
        UserContactListModel l  = mapper.readValue(json,UserContactListModel.class);


    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listModels;
}
```

I understand that the logic is not true, but I can not figure this out very long

Comment: Replace {UserContactListModel.class} with {new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>(){}}

Answer (score 0):

Since your json is array, try as below

```
listModels  = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, UserContactListModel[].class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving a short example try to find out your result.

```
String jsonArray = "[{\"brand\":\"ford\"}, {\"brand\":\"Fiat\"}]";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<Car> cars1 = objectMapper.readValue(jsonArray, new TypeReference<List<Car>>(){});
```

Here for your code-

```
public List<UserContactListModel> getUserLocalContactsData() {
    List<UserContactListModel> listModels = new ArrayList<>();
    String json = "";

    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(ReservedName.USER_LOCAL_CONTACTS_DATA,
            context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sharedPreferences.contains("json")) {
        json = sharedPreferences.getString("json", "");
    }else return listModels;

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        // Convert JSON string from file to Object
        listModels  = mapper.readValue(json,new TypeReference<List<UserContactListModel>>(){});


    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listModels;
}
```